# SQL : Confused with WildCard operators

Tags: sql, sql-server, operators, wildcard, sql-server-2014

what is difference between these two sql statements

```
  1-  select * from tblperson where name not like '[^AKG]%';

  2-  select * from tblperson where name like '[AKG]%';
```

showing same results: letter starting from a,k,g

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (ANSI SQL's LIKE has no such functionality.)

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`like '[^AKG]%` -- This gets you rows where the first character of name is not A,K or G. `^` matches any single character not in the specified set or a specified range of characters. There is one more negation `not`. So when you say `name not like '[^AKG]%'` you get rows where the first character of name is A,K or G.

`name like '[AKG]%` -- you get rows where the first character of name is A,K or G.

The wildcard character `[]` matches any character in a specified range or a set of characters. In your case it is a set of characters.

So both the conditions are equivalent.

Comment: Im confused. `^` doesnt mean start with? here you say `matches any single character not in the specified set `

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza ..when in `[]` it means any character(s) other than the ones specified.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a double 'NOT'. The carrot '^' in your first character match is shorthand for 'not', so you are evaluating 'not like [not' AKG]% IE not like '[^AKG]%'.

Answer (score 0):

1)In the first query you are using 'Not' and '^' basically it is Not twice so it cancels outs
therefore your query is 'Not Like [^AKG]' ==> 'Like [AKG]'

Answer (score 0):

^ a.k.a caret or up arrow.

The purpose of this symbol is to provide a match for any characters not listed within the brackets [] , meaning that normally it wouldn't provide a result for anything that starts with AKG, but since you added the word NOT to the query  , you are basically cancelling the operator, just as if you were doing in math :

(- 1) * (- 1)